# Unable to process more than one MB file by ASMX Service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, event-viewer

Unable to process more than one MB file by ASMX Service even though the file limit set upto 10 MB. Getting the following exception:

```
Event code: 3001 
Event message: The request has been aborted. 
Event time: 10/1/2019 8:58:14 AM 
Event time (UTC): 10/1/2019 6:58:14 AM 
Event ID: cb5b16e465ee4a0cb4885c8e8fdddfrd 
Event sequence: 982 
Event occurrence: 35 
Event detail code: 0

Application information: 
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-1-132143473094866215 
Trust level: Full 
Application Virtual Path: / 

Process information: 
Process ID: 22352 
Process name: w3wp.exe 

Exception information: 
Exception type: HttpException 
Exception message: Request timed out
```

Thank You.

Comment: When the response is too large, the error is different. I think the problem is something else, obviously related to timing out. Check out other questions about this to see the error mesage. Also show your web.config entry for `maxJsonLength`, just to be sure.

Comment: Search SO for `maxJsonLength`.

Comment: @shankar.parshimoni Is your issue solved?
If your issue is solved then I suggest you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the warning is that the execution time exceeds the currently set ASP.NET request execution timeout value.

You need to increase the execution time out value.

set below code in your web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
</system.web>
```

also increase iis site connection time out value.

- Open your IIS, right-click on your site name.
- Then open property "Manage Web Site".
- Then click on "Advanced Settings".
- Expand the "Limits" section,you can set your "connection
  time out".

[image]

after doing changes restart the iis server.